# Consistency checking of a FOL model

Tags: logic, theorem-proving, model-checking, theorem

I am developing a model in First order logic. I would like to prove that it is consistent. Is it possible? Is there any free tool that I can use for doing this?

Or this is impossible due to the Godel theorems?

Best regards.

Comment: This is probably better asked in the Maths StackExchange group, since it does not have to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to check a model consistency. And there are several free open-source tools with this feature out there, like [Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/)

Comment: Protégé deals only with the limited fragment of FOL. See my answer to this questions for more details.